# Confirmation of a conjecture: $3\mid (8n)^5 - k$

Tags: number-theory, conjectures

I have made a conjecture:

> > $$\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{6r : r \in \mathbb{N}\}, \ 3\mid (8n)^5 - k$$
> >
> > Such that $k =$ a constant containing all the digits of $(8n)^5$ except for the last $3$. The order of digits is unecessary.

e.g. Let $n = 1$.

$(8\times 1)^5 = 32768 \Rightarrow k_1 = 32\require{cancel}\cancel{768} \ \land \ k_2 = 23\cancel{768}$

$32768 - 32 = 32736 = 3\times 10912$

or

$32768 - 23 = 32745 = 3\times 10915$

$\therefore 3\mid (8n)^5 - k_1, k_2$

I do not know how to prove/disprove it apart from using computer power and trying to find a counter-example, however this has been tested for all $n \leqslant 10^6$ and I have not found one. Could somebody please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I obtain a contradiction for $n=7$. Then $(8n)^5=56^5=550731776$, and
$56^5-550731=5\cdot23\cdot 4784183$.

Comment: Are you sure? I SWEAR I TESTED IT. Hang on a minute.... I left it running for a week... but there was something I didn't check...

Comment: Oh sorry. Every counter-example there is, my computer did not mention it! It skipped it. My stupid programming.....ok, sorry about that. You get the answer :) $$\color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Comment: $n = 8,9$ are also counter-examples. I was going to delete this post, but then I thought, "well, I think this guy deserves $10$ points."

Comment: Thank you; I know how quickly this can happen, so I test this sometimes by hand, to verify my programming.

Comment: Haha I was going to put a program in for $58a^2 + 1 = b^2$ conjecturing that $b$ is always prime....after this, I tested it by hand and it turns out that $a = 8$ is a counter-example. We fail, we learn...